# Is there a element that shows this pattern of boiling point?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, phase

Is there a compound that turns to gas at a certain temperature but if heated more turns back to liquid and if heated more than turn to gas?

Does it exist naturally? Has a such a substance be found? Can such a substance exist? if yes, then why?

Why couldn't at some temperature molecules interact in such a harmony that they actually cling together?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you take a molecular system in the gas state, and you heat it up (at constant pressure), there is no reason for it to go into a denser, more organized state, such as liquid or solid. As you increase temperature, the interaction energy between molecules becomes smaller compared to thermal energy.

Comment: More a condensed matter physics problem. I could imagine some very strange conditions, maybe involving superfluid helium, adsorbed on something, with magnetic fields... 
Definitely not something you can make at home.
So for ~100% of cases, I agree.

Comment: @ssavec the question asks for an element, hence the simple answer… for other cases, yeah, you could imagine a system frozen where temperature increase would “unlock” some vibration modes/conformations which would in turn alter the molecular interactions… but I think this would have to be extraordinary (i.e. I cannot think of any real example)

Comment: no i meant anything..